# I can't display default image?

Tags: php, html

I want to display the user defined image if its found inside a particular folder, and a default image if it isn't.

```
<img src="user_images/<?php echo file_exists('user_images/'.$user.'.jpg')? $user.'.jpg' : 'img/logo-small.png'?>" alt="profile pic" class="userImage" />
```

this doesn't seem to work. where did I go wrong?

Comment: Which of the 2 images isn't showing? none?

Comment: Is the `$user`.jpg always a .jpg?

Comment: @JeroenBellemans fixed, but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to echo/print the filename.

Try

```
<img src="user_images/<?php echo file_exists('user_images/'.$user.'.jpg')? $user.'.jpg' : 'img/logo-small.png'?>" alt="profile pic" class="userImage" />
```

Comment: What does the resulting HTML code look like? Can you access the image directly by visiting the URL?

Comment: im just gonna use a regular if statement